# Why does relative positioning remove opacity?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple site where there is an image in the background that has 0.3 opacity, and there is also a background color. On top of all that is some text. Here is the HTML:

If I make the position relative, the text is NOT affected by the opacity of the image. If I make don't make it relative, it is affected by the opacity. I am just wondering why relative positioning has such an effect.

```css
.bg-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background: url(img/keyboard.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#welcome {
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #66FCF1;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  /*this is the point of concern*/
}

.first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid first text-center">
  <div id="welcome">
    <p class="welcomeSize">Welcome!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-1">
    <!--the bg image with opacity-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is `z-index`. Even though you already have a `z-index` on `#welcome`, a `z-index` property doesn't take effect until you add a non-`static` `position` to the element with the `z-index`. So adding `position: relative` activates the `z-index` on `#welcome`, putting `#welcome` on top of  `.bg-1` instead of behind it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, elements are loaded in the order they are specified in your html. In this case, your `.bg-1` element loads *after* (and hence, on top of) your `#welcome` element.

Similarly, [`z-index` is only applied to positioned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) (ie. `fixed`, `relative`, and `absolute`). When you apply `position:relative` you are triggering the `z-index` to be applied, and "lifting" the `#welcome` element *above* your background image